# Determine that ExecuteNonQuery executed successfully

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I know if data was inserted in the database successfully, or whether an error occurred when executing `ExecuteNonQuery()`?

```
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "insert into DOCUMENT(NUM_D_ORDRE_DOC,ID_PERSONE,TYPE_DOC,PRIX_DOC,DATE_DE_MISE_EN_CHARGE,DATE_CREATION)values('"+TextBox1.Text+"','1','"+TextBox2.Text+"','"+TextBox4.Text+"','"+TextBox3.Text+"','"+ @DateTime.Now + "');";

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: You can check with proper use of try catch block.

Comment: See also [Get affected rows on ExecuteNonQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059158/get-affected-rows-on-executenonquery). Please read [ask] and try searching before asking a question. Also, go read about SQL injection and parameterize your queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` will throw an exception if the insert fails for some reason.

If you're really paranoid, you can check the return value of the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` method call and validate that it returns one (1) for the record that just got inserted.

Note: Consider using parameter binding instead of string concatenation to avoid subjecting yourself to SQL injection and simple quoting errors.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the return value of ExecuteNonQuery().

Like this:

```
int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It throws exception if any error occurs.

More info: [ExecuteNonQuery Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This should answer your question:

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx