# Entity Framework ExecuteSqlCommand returns -1 while updating table data using stored procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

When I execute

```
int rowsAffected = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Update tablename set Column1='new' where id=5")
```

`rowsAffected` is number of affected rows.

But when I execute the same statement in a stored procedure:

```
int rowsAffected = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("spUpdate_tbl");
```

`rowsAffected` is returned as -1.

How do I get number of rows affected when updating data using a stored procedure
with Entity Framework?

Comment: use ExecuteNonQuery, not ExecuteSqlCommand - also see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059158/get-affected-rows-on-executenonquery

Comment: My psychic powers are telling me you have the line `SET NOCOUNT ON` in your stored procedure.

Comment: is this `code first` or what ?