# How to find out what was last change to SQL db?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a program that is running an UPDATE query. For testing purposes, the query is fixed, just `UPDATE table SET field = 'field_name' WHERE other_field = 'id_field_value'`. I'm using a `MySqlCommand` and executing the query with `sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`. However, I am running it over and over and it keeps on returning 1 row change each time. Running the same query in MySQL GUI tools returns 0 rows affected, as expected. What's the best way to figure out what changes are occurring to the sql db?

My question has been flagged as a duplicate-I am not asking how to get # rows affected by a sql query. I am asking how to find out what changes were made to a sql table when a query keeps on returning 1 row affected when I expect it to return 0.

NEVERMIND, my question was answered in the comments of the duplicate question ([Get affected rows on ExecuteNonQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059158/get-affected-rows-on-executenonquery#comment75128540_10059585)). Turns out ExecuteNonQuery() doesn't return the number of rows that were actually modified, just the 'possible' number of rows that could've been modified. This is frankly much less useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get affected rows on ExecuteNonQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059158/get-affected-rows-on-executenonquery)

Comment: Issue SELECT field FROM table WHERE other_field = 'id_field_value'

Comment: You could change the filter on the update to include `AND field <> 'field_name'` basically making sure you don't reset the same value.

Comment: @juharr That's a good workaround, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` in Connector/NET returns the number of rows that were found, whether they were updated or not (even though [the documentation for `DbCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommand.executenonquery) says “For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command”).

To get the behaviour you want, specify `UseAffectedRows=True` in your connection string ([reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html)), or set `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.UseAffectedRows = true;`.